# Loadrunner 400 error: truncate to 1000 characters

Tags: loadrunner

error message as below snapshot shows, it seems the request parameter's value was truncated, which caused bad request, anyone can help me to analyze what's the root cause, thanks!

Error info as below:
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "truncate to 1000 characters" refers to the value displayed in the snapshot view in VuGen. This was done to improve the loading time of the snapshot viewer and has no effect on actual value received from the server.

Comment: but the error message indicates that 'invalid code, missing end of block', does it mean the requested content was truncated when FCS server is handling the request? not clear about this, thanks!

Comment: I think I was wrong. The message VuGen prints out is "rest of string was truncated" so it may be coming from the server that way. In any case, you should check the server.

Comment: the strange is that it works fine when I manually do the checkin-out function, it only failed with Loadrunner; I'm still at a loss!